# Error Number: 1062 Duplicate entry '465628' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: cartthrob, error, mysql, database-error, duplicate

Running into some serious issues with CartThrob.  All of a sudden I am getting this error when I add an item to the cart and try to view cart or checkout:

It was working last night and sometime over night it all fell apart.
Running EE 2.7.1 and CT 2.4

```
Error Number: 1062
Duplicate entry '465628' for key 'PRIMARY'

INSERT INTO `exp_cartthrob_cart` (`cart`, `timestamp`, `url`) VALUES ('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', 1384949211, 'http://domain.com/checkout/checkout')

Filename: third_party/cartthrob/models/cart_model.php

Line Number: 79
```

Comment: I found this http://blogs.vinuthomas.com/2008/06/18/mysql-error-1062-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-1/

changed the field from int to unsigned bigint which fixed the problem for them

For me, it didn;t seem to work but once I changed it back to INT the error seemed to go away.  (Hopefully for good)

Comment: Please post your solution below as an answer and accept it as correct. The more details you can provide the better for the next person who runs into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this blogs.vinuthomas.com/2008/06/18/… changed the field from int to unsigned bigint which fixed the problem for them For me, it didn;t seem to work but once I changed it back to INT the error seemed to go away. (Hopefully for good)